# How to stop ASP.NET MVC from running on EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am sort of a beginner when it comes to AWS and EC2. There is an EC2 instance that I have access to. I can remote in and everything and I have a node app that I want to run on this instance. I have my node app set up to run on XXXXX on port XX for my instance, but there is already something running on there. It is an ASP.NET MVC application from the former owner of this EC2 instance. How can I essentially stop the instance from using this ASP.NET MVC and instead use my node server?

Comment: You go into IIS most likely and stop the application

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Sorry like I said I’m new to this.

Comment: If you don't need the EC2 instance, just terminate it and create a new one and it won't have anything running on it - what do you mean by "former owner"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not anything related to EC2, it could happen with your local environment.

i would suggest spin a new instance(terminate the old one if not required) or clean/uninstall ASP.NET from existing one.